# Query string for Dropbox events

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there any way to search events with query string or API

`dropbox.com/events?date=30-9-2019`

Works for dates but I would like to search by name of the file / folder in the event.

I recently found recurring disappearance of files/folders and need to investigate when and who deleted them in shared folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to list/retrieve events programmatically unfortunately, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.

The closest thing on the Dropbox API would be to process all of the entries from [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)[[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue)] with path="" and recursive=true, and keep track of the server_modified values manually, but that would be more work and may not give you exactly the right values you're looking for.

(The Dropbox Business API does offer [/2/team_log/get_events](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#team_log-get_events)[[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/teams#team_log-get_events-continue)] but that's for [the Dropbox Business activity log](https://help.dropbox.com/teams-admins/admin/view-activity), and only available to Dropbox Business API apps connected to Dropbox Business teams.)

Comment: It would be nic if you could filter events by type - at this moment is by location and date only. in my case where i lost crazy big amount of data for still unknown reason I would like periodically run DELETED filter and if it happens that it lists 2000 files deletions I would take action.

Comment: @dascorp Thanks for the additional feedback! I'll send this along as well.